# Applying css styles to elements within certain order

Tags: html, css

So I have a situation, where I have a list of elements like these:

```
<li class="a">1</li>
<li class="a">2</li>
<li class="a">3</li>
<li class="b">4</li>
<li class="b">5</li>
<li class="a">6</li>
<li class="a">7</li>
```

Now what I want to achieve is to use CSS queries to apply red background to the first and last occurrence of `a`. So in the example above: 1, 3, 6, 7 will have the background color red.

How can this be achieved using css? I have tried using css siblings queries but I can't find a way to determine when the switch from a -> b happens.

Comment: `li.a:first-of-type`,`li.a:last-of-type` ?

Comment: This case can not be solved using CSS.

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph Nope, won't work. The available selectors as of today, doesn't have one that works for classes, and with your suggestion it will select the first and last `li` if either has the class `a`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a:nth-child(1) {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.a:nth-child(3) {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.a:nth-child(6) {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.a:nth-child(7) {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<li class="a">1</li>
<li class="a">2</li>
<li class="a">3</li>
<li class="b">4</li>
<li class="b">5</li>
<li class="a">6</li>
<li class="a">7</li>
```

you just need to change no which one you want to be make red background

```
.a:nth-child(no will come here ) {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Comment: why this `none repeat scroll 0 0` ?

Comment: none properties show there is not the background image, repeat for colors repeating, scroll for scrolling top to bottom and first 0 for background positions from left and another one for background positions from the top.

Comment: when you give `background: color` rest of the properties go by default, unless specified. there is no effect of `repeat` and `0 0` on when it's `background` color. Anyways, your choice.

Comment: yes, your are right if you want you can remove it, I have just write default rule. Here is simple background modification but when you using wide time it's important to use

Comment: It is asked for a general case, which means the amount of `a` and `b` is not fixed, so if you add one more `.a` in the beginning and you'll see this won't work

Comment: Thanks @RajKumarBhardwaj, but as @LGSon said, I am looking for a generic solution and this depends on me knowing which indexes are with classname `a`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question you need to apply background color red on every occurance first and last child elements. for this please refer the following css code.

```
.a:nth-child(2n+1), .a:nth-last-child(2) {
background: red;}
```

Comment: It is asked for a general case, which means the amount of `a` and `b` is not fixed, so if you add one more `.a` in the beginning and you'll see this won't work